# unable to list packages using package control : install package

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

when I use install package nothing happens and in console this error comes up like this, I have no clue what is this error.
I tried every this I reinstalled the sublime text and ever this but the error is kept on coming.

```
Package Control: Attempting to use Urllib downloader due to WinINet error: Error downloading channel. The requested security package does not exist (errno -2146893051) during HTTP write phase of downloading https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\automatic_upgrader.py", line 111, in run
self.install_missing()
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\automatic_upgrader.py", line 139, in install_missing
if self.installer.manager.install_package(dependency, is_dependency=True):
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\package_manager.py", line 679, in install_package
packages = self.list_available_packages(exclude_dependencies=exclude_dependencies)
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\package_manager.py", line 343, in list_available_packages
repositories = self.list_repositories()
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\package_manager.py", line 271, in list_repositories
channel_repositories = provider.get_repositories()
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\providers\channel_provider.py", line 189, in get_repositories
self.fetch()
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\providers\channel_provider.py", line 86, in fetch
'Error downloading channel.')
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\download_manager.py", line 308, in fetch
return self.fetch(url, error_message, prefer_cached)
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\download_manager.py", line 264, in fetch
return self.downloader.download(url, error_message, timeout, 3, prefer_cached)
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\downloaders\urllib_downloader.py", line 102, in download
self.setup_opener(url, timeout)
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\downloaders\urllib_downloader.py", line 275, in setup_opener
bundle_path = get_ca_bundle_path(self.settings)
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\ca_certs.py", line 50, in get_ca_bundle_path
system_ca_bundle_path = get_system_ca_bundle_path(settings)
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\ca_certs.py", line 139, in get_system_ca_bundle_path
_win_create_ca_bundle(settings, ca_path)
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\ca_certs.py", line 376, in _win_create_ca_bundle
not_after = convert_filetime_to_datetime(cert_info.NotAfter)
File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\Package Control\package_control\ca_certs.py", line 544, in convert_filetime_to_datetime
return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_seconds)
ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing sublime text solved the problem.